# Построение параллельного отрезка

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Как построить параллельный отрезок, заданной длины?

**Как должна работать программа:**
Пользователь выбирает отрезок, который может лежать под различными углами. Далее вводит процент, который будет составлять длину от текущего выбранного отрезка. Потом на основе этого строится новый отрезок параллельный тому который выбрал пользователь (прямые могут накладываться друг на друга). Например пользователь ввел 50%, значит новый отрезок будет в 2 раза меньше выбранного.

**Как работает программа:** Параллельный отрезок заданной длины строится только в том случае если, выбранный отрезок параллелелен оси X.

Проблема заключается только в самой формуле, она не пригодна для случаев когда линия не параллельна оси Х. Не знаю как вывести необходимую формулу так как с матаном и геометрией у меня очень туго. На картинке красным показано два варианта как может располагаться новый отрезок.

```
import arcpy
import os

infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
percent = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # процент от длины текущего отрезка
coord_list = []  # список с координатами старой линии
coord_list2 = [] # список с координатами новой линии
count =0
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    partnum = 0
    for part in row[1]:
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                coord_list.append(pnt.X)
                coord_list.append(pnt.Y)
                count=count+1
            if count == 2:
                x1=coord_list[0]
                y1=coord_list[1]
                x2=coord_list[2]
                y2 = coord_list[3]
                # Находим расстояние
                distance = math.pow(
                    ((math.pow((x2 - x1), 2)) + (math.pow((y2-y1), 2))),
                    .5)
                # Находим сегмент, котрый надо вычесть, чтобы получить текущее растояние
                segment = (distance * int(percent)) / 100
                # Находим расстояние новой линии
                distance2 = distance - segment
                # добавляем координаты 1-й точки
                coord_list2.append([x1, y1])
                # добавляем координаты 2-й точки
                coord_list2.append([x1+x2-x1-distance2, y1+y2-y1])
                # Строится линия
                result = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
                    os.path.dirname(outfc),
                    os.path.basename(outfc), "POLYLINE", spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference)
                feature_class = result[0]
                with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(feature_class, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
                    cursor.insertRow([coord_list2])
        partnum += 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Igor у меня их нет, поэтому решил спросить. Пробовал, вначале находить угол наклона выбранной прямой, потом исходя из этого по формулам x2=x1+d*cosa y2=y1+d*sina, находить координаты второй точки новой прямой, однако ничего не вышло.

Comment: Прямая задется формулой линейного уравнения: `f(x) = m*x + b`. Весь класс параллельных прямых выражается формулой `f(x) = m*x + N`, где `N` - расстояние __по вертикали__ между заданной и прямой и параллельной ей прямой. Чтобы провести прямую параллельную заданной через определенную точку достаточно посчитать разность значений по `Y` между заданной точкой и значением функции известной прямой в точке `X` (подставив в качестве `X` X-координату заданной точки). Так мы получим искомое `N`. Вот и вся математика! PS у линий/прямых нет длины, длина есть у отрезков.

Comment: @MaxU изменил описание, линии исправил на отрезки, добавил картинку. Красным на картинке отметил, то как может располагаться новая прямая. Расстояние N я могу прописать сам, например изменить имеющимся координаты первой точки первого отрезка так (x1; y1+2). Проблема в том что отрезки расположены под разными углами, а новый отрезок имеет другую длину поэтому координаты его второй точки неизвестны. Если бы он имел ту же длину то  можно было аналогично поменять координаты второй точки (x2; y2+2) или вообще не менять, так как меня устроит если новый отрезок будет накладываться на старый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для построения параллельного отрезка нужно найти направляющий вектор единичной длины (**ud**) и перпендикулярный ему вектор (**perp**) с длиной `distance`

Строится точка начала отрезка `(x1', y1')` и затем конечная точка с использованием множителя `ratio` (0.5 для 50%)

```
dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
udx = dx / len
udy = dy / len 
perpx = -udy * distance
perpy = udx * distance

// "left" line start
x1' = x1 + perpx
y1' = y1 + perpy
// "left" line end
x2' = x1' + dx * ratio
y2' = y1' + dy * ratio
```

Для отрезка на другой стороне нужно изменить знак:

```
// "right" line start
x1'' = x1 - perpx
y1'' = y1 - perpy
```